# How to avoid ISPOSTBACK in an asp.net jquery(ajax) application?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, postback

I have an ASP.NET WEB API application using jquery/Ajax. When I select "M1" in my dropdownlist a gridview shows data for Machine 1, when I click "update" button. If change to "M2", the gridview show data for M1 AND M2. It continue to add data. I only want to see data for M1 or M2 and so on. The problem is probadly due to POSTBACK function. How to solve this? Update panel?

```
function update() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/api/stop/',
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: "data",
        success: function (data) { 
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                if (data.machinename == $("#DropDownList11").val() && data.name != $(null).val() && data.overlimit == 1 && data.stopcause ==$(null).val())
                {
                        var _id = data.id;
                        var _machinename = data.machinename;
                        var _stopcause = data.stopcause;
                        var _machinename = data.machinename;
                        var _name = data.name;
                        var _stop1 = data.idlestart;
                        var _stop2 = data.idlestop;
                        var _data = '<tr><td>' + _id + ' </td><td>' + _machinename + '</td><td>' + _name + '</td><td>' + _stop1 + '</td><td>' + _stop2 + '</td><td>';
                        var _data2 = '<option>' + data.id + '</option>'
                        $('table').append(_data);
                        $('#DropDownList5').append($(_data2))
                };
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, My Guess is, the problem is in your append logic, `$('table').append(_data);`. You keep on appending your data to the table and not clearing the previous ones. Just try to clear the data before going in the `$.each` api of `jQuery`. Something like below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/api/stop/',
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: "data",
    success: function (data) {
        $("table tr").remove(); // this line will clear off the previous table tr elements before appending new ones.
        $.each(data, function (i, data) {
            if (data.machinename == $("#DropDownList11").val() && data.name != $(null).val() && data.overlimit == 1 && data.stopcause ==$(null).val())
            {
                    var _id = data.id;
                    var _machinename = data.machinename;
                    var _stopcause = data.stopcause;
                    var _machinename = data.machinename;
                    var _name = data.name;
                    var _stop1 = data.idlestart;
                    var _stop2 = data.idlestop;
                    var _data = '<tr><td>' + _id + ' </td><td>' + _machinename + '</td><td>' + _name + '</td><td>' + _stop1 + '</td><td>' + _stop2 + '</td><td>';
                    var _data2 = '<option>' + data.id + '</option>'
                    $('table').append(_data);
                    $('#DropDownList5').append($(_data2))
            };
        });
    }
});
```

Moreover, I am not sure where is the POSTBACK function that you are mentioning, as best of my knowledge, POSTBACK functions are part of WebForms and not WebAPIs. So, I assume you by POSTBACK method you meant the method `success`.

Comment: It's a webform.  I use web api to communicate over the intranet.

Comment: Then make sure you are not using a server side button. And returning false at the end of your jquery method.

Comment: I used a html input(button) and inserted "return false" in my jquery but nothing changed. It works like before.

Comment: Okay, have you tried the sample code that I shared in my Answer?

Comment: If I push "page reload" on my browser between the two Button update, if works like a want. 1. Select M1 2. Push Update 3.Push reload page. 4. Select M2 5.Push update

Comment: @PeterGadeCarstensen Please try to implement the example I shared above. That would solve the issue if it is not clearing off the previous records. It doesn't seem like a postback issue.

Comment: Thanks, Its works with: $("table tr").remove(); Very simple solution. I am not used to ajax or jquery.

Comment: @PeterGadeCarstensen, Happy to help! Please, make sure to mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: Can I do the same for my dropdownlist5?

Comment: For other queries, you may ask another question by explaining things you want to do. I am sure there would be a change in the scenario.

Comment: @PeterGadeCarstensen I see you haven't accepted the answer, was it not helpful to solve your problem?